# Why is the folder greyed out in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven

[Greyed out folder 'src/test/java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0gzk.png)

Can anyone tell me why is the folder greyed out in eclipse?

Comment: Can you open the folder? Can you create new classes within it? Chances are it's just a visual representation to show it's the JUnit test folder.

Comment: I recommend to read the [New and Noteworthy for Eclipse Photon](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.8/jdt.php) . If you don't like just `Test source folders and dependencies are shown with a darker icon in the build path settings, the package explorer and other locations. This can be disabled in Preferences > Java > Appearance:..`...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since Eclipse Photon, in Java Maven projects source folders containing test code (`src/test/java`) are marked automatically as **test source**.

**Classpath separation** via test source prevents JUnit and other test libraries and code from being used accidentally in the main code (`src/main/java`).

See also:

- [Eclipse Photon - New and Noteworthy - Test sources](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.8/jdt.php#jdt-test-sources)
- [Short video showing this new feature in action](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U-ZTkhek5TU&t=152s)